# How to connect my avr to the computer with usb cable

Tags: avr

I have an avr, but I do not have any sidewall to program it. Is it possible to program an avr with an usb cable without any modules (with four wire available on usb cable)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry but there is no such information to answer your question. I would recommend you to edit your question.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is about programming, not hardware. A better site might be [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is a better place.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You need to program DFU bootlader first.

Many ARM uCs have DFU bootloaders in their ROMs, and IMO it is not worth nowadays to start learning obsolete 8bit architecture